# USER shown in `ps aux` but not found /etc/passwd

Tags: linux, security, users, root, multiuser

`ps aux` output (only line of interest shown)

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
472      24070  0.0  0.7 1636608 59416 ?       Ssl  May09  10:53 grafana-server --...
```

id to username lookup yields nothing

```
$ id -nu 472
id: ‘472’: no such user
```

username to id lookup yields nothing

```
$ id -u 472
id: ‘472’: no such user
```

`/etc/passwd` does not contain any line with 472 anywhere in it.

This user running a program, why is it not listed anywhere?

Comment: Are you running any docker containers on the machine?

Comment: Yes, I am running docker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the info in the comments I'll guess you are running Grafana in a docker container and you are running `ps` on the host.

The 472 user is the grafana user in one of the containers which is why you can't find it in the host's `/etc/passwd` file

Comment: I don't know how users work on linux. But can a user id exist without a username and without any trace in common locations like /etc/passwd or via id lookup? Where can I find 472 listed somewhere on the host? How does Linux decide what privileges a user has? It should have an entry somewhere right? Or does it default to some "minimum rights profile" for such unknown users?

Comment: That user has no records on the host, all it's privileges are sandboxed to within the Linux Network Namespace that the Docker container is bound to.

Comment: At runtime, users are only ids, and the contents of `/etc/passwd` (or any other user database) don’t matter. Privileges are determined by the target of those privileges: files’ ownerships and permissions, ACLs, etc.

Comment: Ok so file permissions are mapped to ids and when we do `ls -l` the system looks up the username for given id and shows that.instead of a numeric id. username is mostly a UI frill for human user. Right?

Comment: usernames are entirely a human UI thing, the system worked purely with numerical ids